# Obtaining names of functions at compile time?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, templates

I'd like to make a small and stupid test framework.

One requirement I would like to fulfill in creating this stupid framework is the ability to add any functions that start with "TEST_" to my function list and one function each for "SETUP_" and "TEARDOWN_".

For example:

```
TEST_MyFirstTest("My fake test"){
   //... test code
}

SETUP_MyTest("setup before each test"){
   //... create all objects to be handled here
}

int main() {
   TESTFRAMEWORK Test = new TESTFRAMEWORK();
   Test.run();
   return 0;
}
```

Obviously I'd define my tests in a separate file, but is there a way to do this? Would I need to use TMP?

Comment: Have you looked at CPPUnit?

Comment: I am using Boost Unit_Test. This is more of an exercise than something  I plan to use professionally. Sort of similar to re-implementing data structures as an instructional exercise.

Comment: Some compilers support `__FUNCTION_NAME` which is a macro that returns the name of the encompassing function.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: I think you mean `__func__` or `__FUNCTION__` - and technically, it's a macro that expands to a string that contains the name - it's subtly different from a macro that expands to the name of the actual function!

Comment: However, I don't think that will help, as `__func__` is only valid within a function, and I don't think that is what this question is about. I'm not entirely sure how you solve the actual question - I've always solved it by writing the actual code for the functions needed...

Comment: Use debug info or a DLL/SO.  Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Does It need to start with TEST_ or you can aleviate a bit and allow it to start as TEST()? For example, instead of `TEST_MyFirstTest("My fake test")`, do as `TEST(MyFirstTest, "My fake test")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to tweak the syntax to:

```
TEST(MyFirstTest, "My Fake Test") {
  // test code...
}
```

Then you could do something like:

```
struct testBase {                                                     
  virtual void run() = 0;                                             
  virtual const char* getDesc() = 0;                                  
};                                                                   

vector<testBase*> global_test_collection;                            

#define TEST(name,desc)                                               \
struct test_##name : public testBase {                                \
  virtual void run();                                                 \
  virtual const char* getDesc() { return desc; }                      \
  static bool init;                                                   \
};                                                                    \
test_##name::init = global_test_collection.append(new test_##name()); \
void test_##name::run()
```

I haven't actually tested this.

You might be able to simplify it by using function pointers instead of virtual functions, but you'd lose the descriptions and might run into issues with what order you do things in.

Comment: I'll test this, but for now I'll accept it. This is pretty slick.

Comment: Ok, I tweaked it and it works great. Excellent stuff man, thanks a lot.